# Не срабатывает mail()

Tags: php, email

Не срабатывает `mail()`, не понимаю в чем причина, помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

```
<?php
    $___notjson=1;
    include 'inc/matras_cfg.php';

    //Форма сообщения
    $title = "Заказ с конструктора"; 
    $to = "dimastik86@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: Матрасик <>\r\n";

    $massiv = unserialize(stripslashes($_GET['massiv']));

    $mess .= "<b>Сверху:</b><br>";
    foreach($massiv as $mtr_up){ 
        $find_down = "_down";
        if(!strstr($mtr_up, $find_down) AND $mtr_up !=  $block){
            $mess .= $matras_name[$mtr_up]."<br>";
        }
    };

    if ($block){
        $mess .= "<br><b>Блок:</b><br>";
        $mess .= $matras_name[$block]."<br>";
    };

    if ($_GET[main]){
        $mess .= "<br><b>Основа:</b><br>";
        $mess .= $_GET[main]."<br>";
    };

    $mess .= "<br><b>Снизу:</b><br>";
    foreach($massiv as $mtr_down){ 
        $find_down = "_down";
        if(strstr($mtr_down, $find_down) AND $mtr_down !=  $block){
        $ms =  str_replace("_down", "", $mtr_down);
        $mess .= $matras_name[$ms]."<br>";};
    };


    $message = '<html>'."\n";
    $message .='<head>'."\n";
    $message .='<title>'.$title.' '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</title>'."\n";
    $message .='</head>'."\n";
    $message .='<body>'."\n";
    $message .= $message_text;  
    $message .='</body>'."\n";
    $message .='</html>';  


    $message_text = "
    <u>Имя заказчика:</u> <b>".$_GET['user_name']."</b><br><br>
    <u>Контактный номер:</u> <b>".$_GET['user_tel']."</b><br><br>
    <u>Адрес доставки:</u> <b>".$_GET['user_adress']."</b><br><br>
    <u>Стоимость заказа:</u> <b>".$_GET['get_price']." руб.</b><br>
    <h2 align='center'><u><b>Заказ:</b></u></h2>
    <u>Размер:</u> <b>".$_GET['size_x']."x".$_GET['size_y']."</b><br><br>".$mess;


    // если была нажата кнопка "Отправить" 
    if ($_GET['user_name'] AND $_GET['user_tel']){
        if (mail($to, $title, $message_text, $headers)){
            print "<h2>Спасибо!</h2><div>Ваш заказ отправлен.<br><br>Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время!</div>";
        }else{
             print "<h2>Извините!</h2><div>Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения.<br>Свяжитесь с администратором сайта!</div>";
        //print $message_text."<br>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>";
        }; 
    };
    $i_err="1";

    if (!$_GET['user_name']){
        $error_form .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Ведите имя!</div>";};
    if (!$_GET['user_tel']){
        $error_form .= "<div>".$i_err++.". Ведите номер телефона!</div>";};

    if ($error_form){
    ?><h2 align="center"><b>Не все заполненно!</b></h2><?
    print $error_form;};
?>
```

Comment: а в простом случае mail() срабатывает ?

Comment: а это не простой случай?) 

все переменные приходят, проверял!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во первых поменяйте

```
if (mail($to, $title, $message_text, 'From:'.$headers))
```

на

```
if (mail($to, $title, $message_text, $headers))
```

т.к. `$headers` уже содержит `From:`

и в From: должен быть email хотя-бы так:

```
From: Матрасик <>\r\n
```

попробуйте

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "Ошибка: $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline<br>";
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
if (mail($to, $title, $message_text, 'From:'.$headers)) {
```

должно выдать ошибку

Comment: Все равно - Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения. (((
*код выше поправил, согласно вашим замечаниям!

Comment: ﻿Ошибка: 2, mail() has been disabled for security reasons, /home/ru/cgi/runphp.php(94) : eval()'d code, 68


Ошибка: 8, Undefined variable: error_form, /home/ru/cgi/runphp.php(94) : eval()'d code, 82

Comment: обратитесь к своему хостеру, почта выключена в php

Comment: я уже понял, спасибо за помощь!